# how to integration masking phone number calling twilio api php

Tags: php

i wanna create a calling between passenger and driver using anonymous phone no. both are not see own no. it actually see the Twilio assign no. how can i integrate in custom PHP and please also tell me the work flow. if u have code must share your git link

Comment: No one "must" do anything, do your own research and write your own code.

Comment: Too Broad and off topic, Seems you didn't put any effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use case in many sharing economy platforms. Twilio website and documentation have sufficient details to enable you build this. Tutorials with code is also available.

Check out these [steps](https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/marketplace-communications/masked-phone-numbers/build) and [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails) .

Steps include ( this is directly copied from Twilio website)

```
STEP ONE
PROVISION TWILIO PHONE NUMBERSPurchase a pool of phone numbers from the Twilio 
self-service portal or the Twilio phone number API. You can search for phone  
numbers with a specific country and area code.

STEP TWO
MAP TWILIO PHONE NUMBERS TO USERSImplement the mapping between the provisioned  
Twilio phone numbers and your users. In this example, xxx-xxxx is associated  
to Arya and Bran's personal phone numbers for the duration of their business 
relationship.

STEP THREE
ARYA CALLS TWILIO NUMBER XXX-XXXXWhen Arya calls xxx-xxxx, Twilio receives the 
call and makes an HTTP request to your web server.

STEP FOUR
YOUR WEB SERVER RETURNS BRAN'S PRIVATE NUMBERYour web server looks up the  
private phone number of Bran associated to xxx-xxxx and returns a TwiML <Dial>  
to Bran's number.

STEP FIVE
THE CALL IS CONNECTEDTwilio connects the call between Arya and Bran. Bran sees 
the call coming in from xxx-xxxx.
```

[image]